# Save VtkVolume as stl file (3d data)?

Tags: vtk

I'm making a function using vtk now.
The process is as follows:

1. Load dicom series
2. we can see only some parts give to value in vtk Piecewise function.
3. write stl file

I need to some function about write vtkVolume to stl data.
How can I save vtkvolume data to stl file?

**MY CODE AS BELOW:-**

```
vtkDICOMImageReader *reader = vtkDICOMImageReader::New();
reader->SetDirectoryName("Dicom_Series");
reader->Update();

vtkPiecewiseFunction* opacitytransfer = vtkPiecewiseFunction::New();
opacitytransfer->AddPoint(-700, 0.0);
opacitytransfer->AddPoint(-101, 0.0);
opacitytransfer->ClampingOff();

vtkColorTransferFunction* colortranster = vtkColorTransferFunction::New();
colortranster->AddRGBPoint(-700, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
colortranster->AddRGBPoint(-101, 54.0 / 255.0, 154.0 / 255.0, 254.0 / 255.0);
colortranster->AddRGBPoint(-100, 237.0 / 255.0, 204.0 / 255.0, 159.0 / 255.0);
colortranster->ClampingOff();

vtkVolumeProperty* volumeproperty = vtkVolumeProperty::New();
volumeproperty->SetColor(colortranster);
volumeproperty->SetScalarOpacity(opacitytransfer);
volumeproperty->ShadeOn();

vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper* volumeMapper = vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper::New();
volumeMapper->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());

vtkVolume* volume1 = vtkVolume::New();
volume1->SetMapper(volumeMapper);
volume1->SetProperty(volumeproperty);

vtkRenderer* aRenderer = vtkRenderer::New();
aRenderer->AddVolume(volume1);
aRenderer->SetBackground(0, 0, 0);

vtkRenderWindow *renWin = vtkRenderWindow::New();
renWin->AddRenderer(aRenderer);
renWin->SetSize(600, 600);
renWin->Render();

vtkRenderWindowInteractor *iren =   vtkRenderWindowInteractor::New();
iren->SetRenderWindow(renWin);

iren->Initialize();
iren->Start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write out a volume image as an STL file.  STL is a surface mesh format, which is completely different data type than an image.  You need to extract an iso-surface from your volume.  To do so, you can use VTK's MarchingCubes filter.

Here's an example:
https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Modelling/MarchingCubes/

And here's the documentation for the vtkMarchingCubes class:
https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkMarchingCubes.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So You mean if i using vtkvolume that time I can't save anyother 3d format?

Comment: A volume is a 3d format, but a fundamentally different kind of 3d format than what you seem to want.  You want a 3d surface, i.e. a collection of triangles or polygons.  A volume is a 3d regular grid that samples an entire block of space, not just a surface. MarchingCubes extracts a surface from the 3d volume sampling.